# Create new context for the iframe with chromedp

Tags: javascript, go, iframe, chromedp

I couldn't find all the pieces that answer my question, so I'm sorry if this question is duplicated.

I'm working with Go and chromedp, and my challenge is to scroll the element in the iframe to somewhere visible.

Unfortunately the iframe's space is very tight in the page, so a lot of inputs and buttons are hidden behind the main page and chromedp's Click command doesn't work as expected because it clicks on the main page where the iframe's element is located at.

The solution I've used until recently was locate the element as regular element like `chromedp.Nodes("iframe", chromedp.ByQuery)}` and execute `element.scrollIntoView()` JS command via `chromedp.EvaluateAsDevTools()` but this recently this solution started failing with error message

```
Reason: exception "Uncaught" (1:4): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollIntoView')
    at <anonymous>:2:5
    at <anonymous>:3:4
```

After researching about it, I've found out that the reason is that JS is executed on the main browser's context instead of the iframe's, and chrome doesn't allow the parent html page to access iframe's html, even when running chrome with  `--disable-web-security` flag.

So, I'm now trying to create a new chromedp's context pointing to the iframe instead of the main browser hoping that would allow run the JS command mentioned above.

Seems that chromedp is not adding a new Target for the iframe, so the code doesn't find the iframe's target anymore.
To find te iframe's target, I'm doing the following way:

```
var tgt *target.Info
targets, _ := chromedp.Targets(testContext)
for _, t := range targets {
  if t.Type == "iframe" && strings.Contains(t.URL, targetUrl) {
    tgt = t
    break
  }
}
```

Could someone please give me a hint about how I could fix my problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: After a lot of try and errors, I just learned that `chromedp.click` in the iframe, chromedp now moves the element to a visible part of the iframe automatically.
So I don't need to scrollelement anymore